# while using vs code, terminal no longer activates the virtual enviroment

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

whenever i open a new terminal window inside vs code, I get this pop-up massage. terminal works just fine, but I no longer can see the activation script that is like  source/...../bin/activated.
here is the actual massage:
***Python virtual environment was successfully activated, even though "venv" indicator may not be present in the terminal prompt.***

Comment: Now the master question: is the virtual environment activated?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3929826/klaus-d yes it is and as i mentioned when i try different commands, it works fine. the thing is I don't understand the "venv" indicator meaning

Answer (score 0):

`venv` is short for "Virtual Environment", and some shells give you an indication in your terminal prompt that you are using the Python interpreter that is located in the virtual environment. Like this (it may look different based on your machine):
`(somevenv-py3.11) user@Users-MBP project %`

For your peace of mind, VSCode is just letting you know that the venv is active even though your terminal settings are such that you will not see this venv indicator.

You can type `which python` into the terminal to see the path to the interpreter being used. Is that the path you expect? (Eg. when you type something like `somepath/venv/bin/activate` <- That's the path you want. Is that the path you get?).

You also may try simply updating VS Code - there's a fix that was just released for some shells like csh and tcsh related to a [similar issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/22822).

Comment: I updated mt vs code and nothing changed. the expected path and the selected python interpreter are both correct and the same. To do more clarification, let me ask my question in another way. what does it mean when it says "venv" indicator may not be present in the terminal prompt.

Comment: Got it. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In some versions of the vscode, it doesn't show any indication for virtual environment. To ensure open python interpreter in the terminal by typing `python3` (or `python` if the version is python-2). And type the following:

```
import sys

print(sys.executable)
```

If the venv is active, you'll get output something like as follows:

```
/path/to/virtual-environment/venv/bin/python3
```